# What steps would it take to hack an Xbox 360 controller to accept input from a computer program?

Tags: remote-control, microsoft

I understand the Xbox 360 encrypts it's signals from controller to console but I'm curious if there is a way to trigger the analogue and button signals on some under-the-hood 'surface' layer that receives inputs before the encryption takes place.

PS: I originally asked this in Game Development Exchange (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28908/is-there-an-sdk-to-write-console-apps-to-simulate-an-xbox-360-controller) where it was suggested I try this Exchange over theirs and even Gaming.

Comment: [They keep telling me to not leave bare links in the comments so here.](http://akishop-customs.com/PS360.html)

Comment: Are you sure you need to disassemble the controller? The controllers that use a USB cable are usable with custom programs. Not too sure about the wireless ones though.

Answer (score 2):

You can hack directly into the physical switches and buttons on the controller. Leave the controller core functionality remain and interface to the console in its standard way. This eliminates the need to do any reverse engineering or other hand waving funny business.

From the standpoint of the computer that would be manipulating the hacked controller interface it becomes easy as 1's and 0's through an appropriate interface to simulate the switches and buttons states.